# Product variants in ShopifyAPI are not being created using ShopifyAPI in Python with error 'The Variant 'Default Title' Already Exists.'

Tags: python-3.x, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I've been trying to create Products on shopify store using ShopifyAPI package in Python given here [ShopifyAPI](https://pypi.org/project/ShopifyAPI/). Following is the code I'm using

```
                variants=[]
                for variant in product_details['product']['variants']:
                    v=shopify.Variant()
                    v.title=variant['title']
                    v.price=variant['price']
                    v.compare_at_price=variant['compare_at_price']
                    # add image to variant
                    v.option=variant['option1']
                    variants.append(v)

                product.variants=variants
                try:
                    status=product.save()
                    if status==True:
                        print('Product variants uploaded')
                    else:
                        print('Product could not be uploaded')
                        print(product.errors.full_messages() )
                except:
                      pass
```

It is giving me the following error : "The variant 'Default Title' already exists."

I've tried first uploading the product and then adding variants. I've also tried adding variants to the product at the time of creation of product but it does not resolve the issue.